# codeigniter output cache doesn't work?

Tags: codeigniter, caching, web

I'm using `$this->output->cache(n)` to cache webpage, but i cannot figure out how does it work.. I didn't find any cache files under `system/cache` folder...and also after I edit the page and show it again, the content changes, so it seems that the page is not really cached. Can anyone give a help?  (i'm using phil's template lib)
my code:

```
function show(){

    $this->output->cache(5);

    $this->load->model('page_model');
    $var = $this->uri->segment(3, 0); //get About page
    $row = $this->page_model->getPage($var);
    $this->template->title('about')
                   ->set_layout('default')
                   ->set_partial('styles', 'css')
                   ->set('data', $row->body)
                   ->build('about');

}
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

Two things, [as outlined in the documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/caching.html):

> Warning: Because of the way CodeIgniter stores content for output, caching will only work if you are generating display for your controller with a [view](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html).

Perhaps not using the "native" views is an issue?

Additionally:

> Note: Before the cache files can be written you must set the file permissions on your application/cache folder such that it is writable.

Are you sure your `application/cache` directory has the correct permissions?

Comment: Hi Colin and Philip, thank you for your reply! But is there other ways to use this cache method? because it seems that i cannot get rid of the template, i have to use it to build the site...  Also,how to change the permission? I cannot find cache folder under system, but there is a cache folder under application... Sorry, i'm new to CI

Comment: @Mario: Regarding your last question, that was my mistake. The directory is indeed `application/cache`. Regarding how to make CI's cache method work without CI views, you'd have to take a look "under the hood" of the [Output class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html), find out how it works, and extend it as needed.

Comment: @Mario: I forgot to address your other question - "How to change permissions?" It depends on what platform you're on, but you can easily find instructions for Windows, Linux, etc. by [Googling for it](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=change+directory+permissions). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Debug this file and check it's actually writing the cache:
system/core/Output.php

```
// Do we need to write a cache file?  Only if the controller does not have its
// own _output() method and we are not dealing with a cache file, which we
// can determine by the existence of the $CI object above
if ($this->cache_expiration > 0 && isset($CI) && ! method_exists($CI, '_output'))
{
    $this->_write_cache($output);
}
```

This works well for me:

```
function _output($content) {
        // Load the base template with output content available as $content
        $data['content'] = &$content;

        $this->output->cache(600);

        $output = $this->load->view('base', $data, true);

        $this->output->_write_cache($output);

        echo $output;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your application/cache directory has the correct permissions?

you you to directories application/cache in cpanel , permissions become 777 is OK